# Get Table Name of PostgreSQL Event Trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, eventtrigger, postgresql-triggers

I have multiple tables in a PostgreSQL 9.6 database which changes I want to monitor and handle in an extern application.

Handling only data changes wasn't hard, but now I want to monitor structure changes of my database to be stored. This is what I have:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_structureChanged()
    RETURNS event_trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbchanged SET changed=2 WHERE table_name = TG_ARGV[0];
    RETURN NEW;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


CREATE EVENT TRIGGER testData_struc
    ON ddl_command_end 
    WHEN TAG IN ( 'CREATE TABLE', 'ALTER TABLE', 'DROP TABLE' )
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_structureChanged();
```

When the `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` gets called, I want to parse the table that the changes have been made to. The official PostgreSQL documentation didn't really help me - I also may have not fully understood some parts.

So how do I parse the table on that the `EVENT TRIGGER` fired on? Is it stored inside a variable?

Comment: For `CREATE TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` you can save list of tables which you currently have  and then comparing which values are added or removed using `information_schema.tables`, so you can catch table name. This is more difficult for `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: @OtoShavadze Thank you, do you have any idea managing the procedure for `ALTER TABLE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html#PG-EVENT-TRIGGER-DDL-COMMAND-END-FUNCTIONS), you can call the function `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`, which will return one row per affected object.

You can either use the result column `object_identity` which contains a textual description of the affected object, or `classid` and `objid`, which contain the object ID of the catalog table that contains the object and the object ID of the affected object.

Comment: Does _object_ stand for the table name that was affected?

Comment: Yes. For `DROP TABLE` it would be a table, for `DROP TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY` it would be a full text search dictionary.

Comment: Big thanks to you! I scrolled a bit further down the link you posted, and there's documentation for _Table Rewrite_ events. Is that equivalent to a `ALTER TABLE` event?

Comment: Only `ALTER TABLE` statements that rewrite the table.

Comment: @torblerone - I think you need upvote answer, if you find, that was helpful